# MS Flow - How do I achieve "Automatically reject the document if it is changed before the workflow is completed."?

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-flow

I am new MS Flows and trying to achieve the same SP2010 OOB approval WF feature... Reject document if it is changed before the workflow is completed.
I do see an action "Get changes for an item or a file (properties only)". Looks like this identifies only the property changes not the file change. What action I need to use to reject the document if file content is changed when workflow is in progress?

Comment: Could you clarify what tasks the current instance of the MS Flow is waiting for? Is it waiting for an approval? I that case, you probably could lock the document from within the MS Flow so that no one can edit it prior approval process is complete.

Comment: Here is an [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/power-apps-power-automate/locking-a-file-for-approval/m-p/876434) that talks about locking the file when Flow starts and unlock after it ends. However, you could check version changes using MS flow as well

Comment: Yes, it waits for an approval. Locking the file looks like a workaround. Isn't there any direct way? How do I ensure the version change is only due to the file content change not for any other properties?

Comment: There is no such action in Power Automate, you will have to use a workaround for this request. A flow instance does not check for the changes on the object during the Approval task. If you want to keep the version number of the document, locking it will be the ideal solution.

Comment: Version number change is ok.. but should be able to identify the change is due to file content change not because of other properties of file. If yes, can you please explain or provide an example.

Comment: If I enable Content Approval would it help to prevent anybody making changes to the document when workflow is in progress?

Comment: I think we can find when document content is changed by looking into the version metadata. Take a look into my response and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for putting a lot of effort... looks like its a very complex way and I do not dare to attempt it. Few more points (just FYI).. the trigger of my workflow is For a selected file (manual start). Anyways trigger does not matter much here. I do see "Has Column Changed:" and "Has Column Changed:Sensitivity".. I did not get what Sensitivity does here.. can we leverage these two fields and achieve it? And even if we are able to send an email (only once) to initiator if file is changed that should also be fine or update a column like FileChanged Yes/No.. rather than rejecting the WF.

Comment: I went for locking file (check out/check in) option.. that appears the easiest workaround. I was able to convince client. Thanks a bunch for all your support. I am event accepting the below solution, though I have not tried it. I feel we can optimize a bit instead of fetching all versions get only $top one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having analyzed the versions' history of SPO documents from the output of a **[Send an HTTP request to SharePoint]** action in MS Flow, I think, we can use **MediaServiceMetadata**, which contains **lastStreamUpdateTime**, for checking whether the File/Document **Content** or  **column values** are changed.

In my testing, I found that **lastStreamUpdateTime** is updated only when the file's **content** is changed.

Here's is a sample of **MediaServiceMetadata** property value:

```
 "MediaServiceMetadata": "{\"ctag\":\"\\\"c:{be827ad2-e597-441b-9a92-7df9a61556f3},6\\\"\",\"generationTime\":\"2020-11-02T02:18:58.3346095Z\",\"lastStreamUpdateTime\":\"2020-11-02T02:18:58.3346095Z\",\"modules\":[{\"module\":\"AIPLabelExtract\",\"version\":1},{\"module\":\"OfficeBundleGeneration\",\"version\":1}],\"officeBundle\":{\"ctag\":\"\\\"c:{be827ad2-e597-441b-9a92-7df9a61556f3},6\\\"\",\"fatalError\":false,\"version\":\"4.1342833475\",\"generationTime\":\"2020-11-02T02:18:57.3814502Z\",\"generationReason\":\"AnalysisPipeline\"}}"
```

I've also noticed that there is a little delay between the timestamp the version is created and the timestamp value in lastStreamUpdateTime. Most likely some background process updates **lastStreamUpdateTime**.

**High-Level Concept of the Flow steps**

1. When a document is uploaded to the SPO Library, MS Flow kicks in for trigger **[When an item is created]**
2. At the beginning of the Flow, store the Flow start timestamp into a variable
3. Initialize a couple of more variables as shown in the screenshot.
4. Add [Start and wait for an approval] action with options *Approve*, *Reject*, *Cancel* etc
5. Once the document review outcome is received in the Flow, process *Reject* and *Cancel* as normally you would
6. If the outcome is *Approve*, verify if the Document **content** was changed by comparing the Flow starting timestamp with the value of lastStreamUpdateTime in MediaServiceMetadata,
   that is, **lastStreamUpdateTime > Flow Starting Timestamp**
7. If the document **content** was changed after the flow was started, set it's status to "Edited Prior Approval" or whatever suits the business

**See the screenshots and further explanation below**

[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Detail 2

[image]

### Detail 3

[image]

**Expressions 1, 2, 3**

```
1.

split(
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
 string(body('Parse_JSON')?['d']?['results'][0]['MediaServiceMetadata']), '[', ''), ']', ''), '{', ''), '}', ''), '"', ''), '\',''), ',')

2.
item()

3.
if( greater( length(body('Filter_array')),0), replace(body('Filter_array')?[0], 'lastStreamUpdateTime:', ''), variables('varStartTimestamp'))
```

### Detail 4

[image]