# What happens if multiple changes are made on an item of a SP list which has approval process in place

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning, approval-process

I have developed some flow in MS flow for managing some SP lists.

MS flow sends an approval email to the admin for a change.If users keep editing the item the admin recives more emails. What happens if the admin do not approve them in order?

My flow is as below:

[image]
[image]
I have noticed that if the admin approves them out of chronolocal order, no issue appears, and every approved item becomes the most recent one even if it is not the latest one. Is there any way to override this is flow?

I have noticed that if the admin approve the latest version but reject one of the earlier email my flow sotcks in a loop (i.e. shown bythe  red arrow)? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think you should leave the item editable while the last approval is in process.
The flow itself does not lock or identify the status of the item, as you have already known, so it starts a new instance every time it is triggered.

These flow instances run independently and cannot override the actions of another, it just changes the item as designed in the process. So the last approved version becomes the latest version.

And to avoid the situation you describe, you can either manipulate with the item-level or user permission (as we previously discussed in this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286885/is-there-a-way-to-stop-editing-an-item-when-the-approval-status-is-pending-in-sp/286929)), or you can check out another [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286333/ms-flow-how-do-i-achieve-automatically-reject-the-document-if-it-is-changed-b) for idea of auto-rejection.

Comment: Hi @Chelsea_MSFT, I am implementing the user permission level, and thank you for help there too. As soon as I am done with Permission level, I will update my other post too.